# What does this error mean when sending a post request through react? "500 Internal Service Error - Paused on Promise Rejection"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, post, async-await

[image]

I've spent hours trying to figure this out and a 500 internal service error is just so vague. I think it has something to do with the async functions i'm using but not sure. below is my code. I'm simply just fetching different dropdown list data to create 3 different dropdowns on my front end and then submitting that form. it is telling me the error is somewhere in my handlesubmit function..

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

function FormSalesRecord() {
    const [salesRecords, setAutomobiles] = useState([])
    const [salesPersons, setSalesPersons] = useState([])
    const [customers, setCustomers] = useState([])

    const [sales_price, setSalesPrice] = useState("");
    const [sales_person, setSalesPerson] = useState("");
    const [customer, setCustomer] = useState("");
    const [automobile, setAutomobile] = useState("");

    const handleSalesPriceChange = (event) => {
      const value = event.target.value;
      setSalesPrice(value);
    }
    const handleSalesPersonChange = (event) => {
      const value = event.target.value;
      setSalesPerson(value);
    }
    const handleCustomerChange = (event) => {
      const value = event.target.value;
      setCustomer(value);
    }
    const handleAutomobileChange = (event) => {
      const value = event.target.value;
      setAutomobile(value);
    }

    //fetch data from various sources for all dropdown lists
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const url1 = 'http://localhost:8100/api/automobiles/';
      const url2 = 'http://localhost:8090/api/sales/salesperson/';
      const url3 = 'http://localhost:8090/api/sales/customer/';
      const response1 = await fetch(url1);
      const response2 = await fetch(url2);
      const response3 = await fetch(url3);

      if (response1.ok && response2.ok && response3.ok) {
        const data1 = await response1.json();
        const data2 = await response2.json();
        const data3 = await response3.json();
        setAutomobiles(data1.autos);
        setSalesPersons(data2.salespersons);
        setCustomers(data3.customers);
        console.log("hello2")
      }
    }

    useEffect(() => {
      fetchData();
    }, []);

    const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
      event.preventDefault();

      const data = {};
      console.log('hello')

      data.sales_price = sales_price;
      data.sales_person = sales_person;
      data.customer = customer;
      data.automobile = automobile;
      console.log(data)

      const salesRecordUrl = 'http://localhost:8090/api/sales/new/';
      const fetchConfig = {
        method: "post",
        body: JSON.stringify(data),
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
      };

      const response = await fetch(salesRecordUrl, fetchConfig);
      const newSalesRecord = await response.json();

      sales_price('');
      sales_person('');
      customer('');
      automobile('');

    }

    return (
        <div className="row">
          <div className="offset-3 col-6">
            <div className="shadow p-4 mt-4">
              <h1>Record a new sale</h1>
              <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} id="create-salesrecord-form">
              <div className="mb-3">
                  <select value={automobile} onChange={handleAutomobileChange} required name="automobile" id="automobile" className="form-select">
                    <option value="">Choose an automobile by VIN</option>
                    {salesRecords.map(auto => {
                        return (
                            <option key={auto.vin} value={auto.vin}>
                                {auto.vin}
                            </option>
                        )
                    })}
                  </select>
                </div>
                <div className="mb-3">
                  <select value={sales_person} onChange={handleSalesPersonChange} required name="sales_person" id="sales_person" className="form-select">
                    <option value="">Choose a sales person</option>
                    {salesPersons.map(salespersons => {
                        return (
                            <option key={salespersons.name} value={salespersons.name}>
                                {salespersons.name}
                            </option>
                        )
                    })}
                  </select>
                </div>
                <div className="mb-3">
                  <select value={customer} onChange={handleCustomerChange} required name="customer" id="customer" className="form-select">
                    <option value="">Choose a customer</option>
                    {customers.map(customer => {
                        return (
                            <option key={customer.name} value={customer.name}>
                                {customer.name}
                            </option>
                        )
                    })}
                  </select>
                </div>
                <div className="form-floating mb-3">
                  <input value={sales_price} onChange={handleSalesPriceChange} placeholder="Sales Price" required type="numerical" name="sales_price" id="sales_price" className="form-control"/>
                  <label htmlFor="sales_price">Sales Price</label>
                </div>
                <button className="btn btn-primary">Create</button>
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      );

}

export default FormSalesRecord
```

I tried console.logging but not much help. I'm just getting vague 500 intenral service errors. I checked all my url paths they are good, the client and other end of the app are good, my ports are good.

Comment: Obviously an unhandled promise rejection is in effect. I would suggest you to implement error handling in your async code with `try catch` and log inside `catch`.

Comment: It means the error has nothing to do with any front-end code like React or your POST request itself, the _server_ experienced an unrecoverable error while handling the request and is letting you know that it failed, and whoever runs that server should be told about that so they can fix it. Of course, if this is your _own_ server code then your server should have an error log somewhere and you should focus on that instead.

Comment: Yes the server is my own docker container port 8090 as seen on the code

Comment: So i looked in the docker container error logs and it says "ValueError: cannot assign value to "SaleRecord.sales_person". Must be a "SalesPerson" instance.... now that means something is up with my code and im not fetching an instance of the object property. Maybe its something in my models or views code?